# Flask sqlAlchemy is deleting the data in the database on every exit of terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I followed the instructions provided in the quick start page of the 
http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/#quickstart.
But even after doing the autoflush : false and autocommit : false, the data base gets erased everytime i quit the terminal.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={"autoflush":False,"autocommit":False})
```

After this configuration still every time i exit the flask terminal the DB data 
gets erased!

```
>>> users = User.query.all()
[<User u'admin'>, <User u'guest'>]
>>> admin = User.query.filter_by(username='admin').first()
<User u'admin'>
```

Every time i exit flask terminal the whole User table is gone !

PS: Any blog with flask and angular token based authentication is much appreciated :) Along with SQLAlchemy setup !

Comment: Have you added created objects to session, and committed session? Could you post whole code? Have you checked if data is written in database when application is running?

Comment: Help others help you and provide [mcve].

Comment: @IljaEverilä It's resolved i used Schema and db.Model everything went fine post that, i was doing the db.session.commit, but still it was deleting it.

Comment: @PerunSS I have done all that ! But the issue was something else.

Answer (score 1):

Its most likely because you aren't committing your additions to the database. Have a look at [this](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/queries/%20this) in the SQLAlchemy docs, and see that it says that 'inserting data into the database is a three step process'. You would have to add:

```
>>> db.session.add(admin)
>>> db.session.commit()
```

I believe this could be accomplished via setting 'autocommit' to 'True', but I have not tried that method.

Comment: It's resolved i used Schema and db.Model everything went fine post that, i was doing the db.session.commit, but still it was deleting it

Comment: @RaghavendraSS can you then post the answer here, if you managed to resolve this issue. Because I am also facing the same problem